# Limit view path to one domain

Tags: views, 9, domain-access

I currently have a Drupal 9 site running with [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) and a view with a relative path like *contact*. The site currently has two domains, linking the page to both domains like so:

- sub.domain.com/contact
- sub2.domain.com/contact

How can I limit this view to sub.domain.com/contact only?